# Unsubscribe feature not working on SAP cloud platform CF for Multi-tenant SAAS application

Tags: multi-tenant, sap-cloud-platform

developed a multi tenant SAAS App over SAP SCP CF ,did subscription as per SAP help and blogs ,and implemented the delete call back as mention below in node JS ,Unsubscribe feature is not working ,it just stay as subscribed,it was working earlier in global account but not anymore now.
refer the [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/09/17/developing-multitenant-applications-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloud-foundry-environment/).
Same is the issue with sample inventory management app.

```js
/* 
 Callback - 2: On unsubscribing to the application, the method deletes the subscription.
*/
router.delete('/callback/v1.0/tenants/*', function (req, res) {res.status(200);});
```

on unsubscribe nothing happen and it stays as subscribed ,it was working earlier in global account ,but not working for any of the SAAS multi tenant app now post subscription ,subscription is working fine.

Comment: Shouldn't `*` be replaced with id of resource you're trying to delete?

Comment: id is replaced at run time ,this was working earlier with same call back implementation ,now suddenly it has stooped working and in log following error can be traced whcih is failing due to bad gateway:"DELETE /callback/v1.0/tenants/<Subscriber tenantid> HTTP/1.1" 502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by itself closing it.